# Alternative to Phplivedocx which can change images dynamically in template

Tags: php, pdf, docx, doc

For my web-application i use phplivedocx for docx/pdf generating reports. But now i need to insert images, that user will upload to my web-site, to the docx template. On the phplivedocx forums i found that this software doesn't support this feature.
Is there any other tools, that can produce docx/pdf pages from template, and can also change/insert pictures to it?

*Edit1: Found an interesting article on the phplivedocx forum. Man create a template with standard image (example.png). After it he use phplivedocx for changing text in template. After it, he unpack docx and replace example.png with new image.
It's very nice, but how to unpack docx, replace file and set attributes for image in php?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[OpenTBS](http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php) can create DOCX (and other OpenXML files) dynamic documents in PHP using the technique of templates.

No temporary files needed, no command lines, all in PHP.

**And it can add or delete pictures.** The created document can be produced as an HTML download, a file saved on the server, or as binary contents in PHP.

It can also merge OpenDocument files (ODT, ODS, ODF, ...). Nevertheless it cannot create PDF files like PhpLiveDocx.

http://www.tinybutstrong.com/opentbs.php